# jQuery $.get/$.ajax passes HTTP status code 200 instead of expected status code of 201 or 202

Tags: ajax, http, jquery

I've a server that returns HTTP status code 200, 201, and 202 from the same url. In Chrome, I've confirmed with the Network debugging panel that the Status Code is what I expect it to be (i.e. 200, 201 or 202). I rely on that status code to determine the next step.

I'd expect that the callbacks for jQuery (version 1.5.2) AJAX requests to set `jqxhr.status` to the status code that the server sends. However, the status code is always 200, even if the code sent by the server is 201 or 202.

In other words, the following code prints `Code: 200` regardless of what the server sends.

```
$.get(url, {}, function (data, textStatus, xhr ) {
    alert("Code: " + xhr.status);
});
```

Why is this happening, and more importantly, how can one get the actual status code in a jQuery AJAX callback for `$.get` or `$.ajax`?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: any chance you are using JSONP or cross-domain `GET` request?

Comment: Maybe this will be of some help: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8211

Comment: KrisIvanov: No JSONP or cross-domain. It's a request of the usual sort.

Comment: See [this bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8211) and see if it's related; wondering what happens if you use a `$.ajax` and report the status in both the code handler and success.

Comment: Bug 8211 seems only tangentially related - i.e. jQuery doesn't properly handle `statusCode` and `success` handlers. This seems to be a strange truncation of the status code - I'd think there'd be some indication in e.g. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js, but I don't see anything that would obviously change the `jqXHR.status` to 200 from 201/202.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I have experienced jQuery is just not set up very well for handling actual status codes in the response. You can try just doing a manual AJAX call using some good old bare bones JS and handle the status yourself.

Here are a few tutorials on how to do so.

http://www.degraeve.com/reference/simple-ajax-example.php

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

request.status is where you should be able to access the status code in  your request object. Here is another page showing a little bit about how to access even more granular information about the status of the request.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ajaxintro3/

Hope that helps you nail it!

Comment: Thumallen is right, it's either all or nothing. Catching redirect via jquery ajax is unpleasant